# How to fix some divs on top while scrolling using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, affix

I am using bootstrap in Angular 2 project and I want to freeze couple of divs(with ids as filters and categories in the code) on top always, while user scrolls down the page.

This is the code that I have in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ugufn63z/4/)

Code Snippet:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/overview">Overview</a></li>
                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/insights">Insights</a></li>
            </ul>






        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->


    </div>
</nav>


<div id="filters" class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 60px" >

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <button>Filter 1</button>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
       <button>Filter 2</button>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="categories" class="container-fluid"  >
    <div class="row">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li><a routerLink="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div style="background: blue; height: 800px;">
              Trend Chart
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div style="background: green; height: 800px;">
              Bar Chart
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

I have tried using bootstrap's 'affix', but it is breaking the scroll and the margins of 'filters' and 'categories' divs, as can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ugufn63z/5/)

Kindly let me know if I am missing anything else that needs to be added for affix to work.

Comment: Are you try using `position fixed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to use `position: fixed` and `z-index: 1030` CSS with your div

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugufn63z/10/)

## Use this CSS in your div

```
<div id="filters" class="container-fluid" 
style="margin-top: 60px; position: fixed; z-index: 1030;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <button>Filter 1</button>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
       <button>Filter 2</button>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashiqur. I was able to fix the filters and categories divs. However, when I scroll, the content(blue\green divs) still doesn't stop below those divs.  To make it clear, in the following fiddle : `https://jsfiddle.net/ugufn63z/7/` , the blue\green div shouldn't cross the red line while user scrolls. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugufn63z/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the style attribute "position:fixed" in both the div you want to be fixed.
Also set z-index value above 100. (this is to show the fixed div over all other div while scrolling).

Example:

```html
<div id="filters" class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 60px;position:fixed;z-index:999;" >

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <button>Filter 1</button>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
       <button>Filter 2</button>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="categories" class="container-fluid" style="position:fixed;z-index:999;" >
    <div class="row">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li><a routerLink="#">Sub Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="#">Sub Category 2</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div style="background: blue; height: 800px;">
              Trend Chart
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div style="background: green; height: 800px;">
              Bar Chart
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```